# Call to a member function getIdFieldName() on a non-object in /Core/Model/Abstract.php on line 151

Tags: magento-1.9

I get this error message on products page, rest other pages are fine. I have absolutely no clue about this error.

```
 public function getIdFieldName()
{
    if (!($fieldName = parent::getIdFieldName())) {
        $fieldName = $this->_getResource()->getIdFieldName();
        $this->setIdFieldName($fieldName);
    }
    return $fieldName;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I  have learnt never disable `<Mage_Log>`.I guess this extension does a lot then just writing logs to database. My issue is resolved after I enabled it again.