# Fatal error: Call to a member function getIdFieldName() on a non-object in abstract.php on line 151

Tags: magento-1.9, php, model, fatal-error

> Magento ver. 1.9.2.0

I have recently setup a clone staging environment of my live site for testing purposes. The backend and front-end home & other pages are loading fine. Except when I browse product pages, I see the following error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getIdFieldName() on a
>   non-object in html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line
>   151

See image below for reference.

[image]

Things that I have tried:
I have re-copied the `html/app/etc/config.xml` file from live to staging via FTP. Didn't work

Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: Which version of magento are you using?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.2.0

Answer (score 2):

This issue could be due to different reasons.

**1** - Firstly start by cleaning your cache and check.

**2** - Then make sure you have not disabled Mage_log as described [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/99992/5913)

To do that you execute this in your magento docroot:

```
grep -A 5 -r '<Mage_Log>' app/etc/modules
```

You should see something like this:

```
<Mage_Log>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>core</codePool>
```

Next check in the admin panel in

> System->Configuration->Advanced->Advanced

see if the module output is enabled there as well.

**3** - Finally this issue happens when there is no resource defined for a given Model. To find out which is the Model that is failing you can add a log to this file:

> app/Mage.php in line 254.

It should look like this:

```
public static function registry($key)
{
    if (isset(self::$_registry[$key])) {
        return self::$_registry[$key];
    }

    Mage::log(self::$_registry[$key], 1, 'issue.log');
    return null;
}
```

Then you can check your log file in here: `var/log/issue.log`

Or if you want to do it quick and dirty do it like this:

```
public static function registry($key)
{
    if (isset(self::$_registry[$key])) {
        return self::$_registry[$key];
    }

    die(self::$_registry[$key]);
    return null;
}
```

Make sure to revert the code changes once you find the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, How do I know if Mage_log is disabled/enabled?

Comment: I updated the answer with more details, please check and let me know if this works for you. But I suggest you go to step 3 directly

Comment: @lloiacono thanks for the answers.. i am getting this error randomly on admin side.
And its solving after few clicks on different menu items and its happens very randomly on different areas,
I am getting an empty response when dusing die.
I tried to take the $key  and its "_resource_singleton/core/website". 
I am using redis for cache.

Answer (score -1):

This is the database error, Database is not installing or import propery there is the reason max_execution_time is time out . please go to php.ini file and search max_execution_time and increase this.

More Information [please visit here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqJOohTRCgE)

Problem are resolved

Comment: Hello @KamleshKumar - Without any doubt this can not be the correct answer. If, for what ever reason, the `app/etc/local.xml` would be missing, Magento would show you the install setup. Any other issues that might could be in this file (assuming it is present) would lead to completely different errors.